# Why do signatures of make_shared and allocate_shared differ for the args to be forwarded?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, make-shared, universal-reference

In order to create a `std::shared_ptr` for a given type `T`, there are two ways among the others: [`std::allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) and [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).
The main difference (or at least, the one I'm interested in for this question) is that the former does all memory allocations by means of a copy of a given allocator.

From the documentation, `std::allocate_shared` has the following signature:

```
template< class T, class Alloc, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared( const Alloc& alloc, Args... args );
```

On the other side, `std::make_shared` is depicted as:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

For both of them it is stated that:

> args... - list of arguments with which an instance of T will be constructed.

Everything seems right since now (the extra allocator, the arguments, and so on).
Anyway, as far as I've understood, both of them should declare arguments as *universal references* and this is not the case (at least, from what I see in the documentation).

In other terms, shouldn't the signature of `std::allocate_shared` be the following?

```
template< class T, class Alloc, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared( const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args );
```

Is it right for them to be different or is it a mistake of that site?
If that's the first case, what have I missed in my reasoning?

Comment: The wiki is wrong. See  [util.smartptr.shared.create].

Comment: cplusplus.com does it right : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocate_shared/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relies on false resources

Comment: @DavidHaim *False resources*? O.o

Comment: cppreference has a typo

Comment: So, anyone want to edit cppreference to fix it?

Comment: cppreference HAD a typo. (There are more of them on that page, but minor ones.) @Yakk done.

Comment: Well, nice, at least this question has been useful to fix *cppreference*.

Comment: @skyp useful question, just not useful *any more* now that it has been fixed.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I'm not upset, don't worry!! I understand why it has been closed, it makes sense indeed. Thank you. :-)